# Github vs bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, git, github

Вот что мне нужно:

У меня 1 проект php

Я хочу чтобы была несколько закрытых веток и так же была одна открытая ветка для всех
любой разработчик мог эту ветку разветвлять

Так же я не хочу ничего платить и чтоб не было ограничений на размер исходника

Что больше всего подходит github или bitbucket?

Comment: Пожалуй, скорее подойдет битбакет

Answer (score 3):

Гитхаб для этого вообще никак не подойдет- на нем нет приватных реп бесплатных.